# Some UIPrintInteractionController options are not working

Tags: ios, printing

I am printing PDF and Image data from my phone to the print simulator.  The output to the printer all looks good except that the options don't appear to work.  (Specifically showsPageRange and Color on the presented dialog)
1) In code (as seen below) I set `showsPageRange = NO` but when the print dialog appears it still has the option to change the page range.
2) If I set `showsNumberOfCopies = NO` then this option doesn't show up.  (As it should not since I set it to NO, but others don't appear to be working.)
3) Regardless of what I pick in the print dialog, the options don't seem to change.  For example, I'm sending in a color image and if I select black and white then it is still sent to the printer as color.  If I pick print 1st page then it still sends the entire document to the printer.

Here is my code:

```
+(void)print:(id)data JobName:(NSString *)jobName Location:(UIBarButtonItem *)location {
    UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = jobName;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.printingItem = data;

    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = NO;
    printController.showsPageRange = NO;

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pc, BOOL completed,
      NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){
            NSLog(@"Print failed - domain: %@ error code %ld", error.domain,
                  (long)error.code);
        }
    };

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [printController presentFromBarButtonItem:location animated:YES
                   completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
        [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar problem - I set showsNumberOfCopies to YES, I see that it shows "1 Copy", but no stepper to change the value...